# list index out of range Python

Tags: python, lista

Tenho listas com números em formato de string e espaços vazio. Primeiro quero tirar os espaços vazios, e depois quero converter pra float. Mas logo no primeiro `for` aparece o erro:

> if (x[i]=='' or y[i]==''): IndexError: list index out of range

Como isso é o possivel se o `for` vai até len(x)?

```
def convert_and_eliminate(x,y):

for i in range(0,len(x)-100):
    if (x[i]==''):
        x.pop(i)
        #y.pop(i)

for i in range(0, len(x) - 1500):
    print x[i]
    #x[i]=float(x[i])
    #y[i]=float(y[i])
for i in range (0,1500):
    x.pop()
    y.pop()
```

Comment: Da um exemplo (minimo possível) do que poderia ter em `x` e em `y`, pq o range vai até `len(x)-100`?

Answer (score 1):

Quando você da lista.pop(elemento), você diminui o tamanho da lista de 1. Então se você tinha uma lista de tamanho 10, por exemplo, e dá pop, a lista passa a ter tamanho 9. E quando você tenta indexar o décimo elemento dá index out of range.
Sugiro que vc guarde o tamanho da lista em uma variável length, por exemplo. Então faz um loop

```
while i < length:
    if lista[i] == "":
         x.pop(i)
         lenght = length - 1
    i = i + 1
```

Tentei fazer a identação correta, mas estou no celular. Espero que dê para entender.
Algumas considerações:

- Vc pode substituir range(0,len(x)-100) por range(len(x)-100).
- Não entendi o pq de ir até len(x) - 100.
- Não é uma boa prática usar números hardcoded tipo esse 100 e esse 1500.

Comment: Muito obrigado! O problema era exatamente esse!

Comment: De nada. Da um ok aí pra pessoas verem que está resolvido. XD

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o erro seja na segunda parte da validação (`y[i]==''`); o `for` vai até o tamanho máximo do `x`, como você falou, mas se o `y` for menor, receberá esse erro.

Se precisar realmente dessas condições, altere o código:

```
if (x[i]=='' or (len(y) <= i and y[i]=='')):
```

Comment: Não é esse o caso , cheguei até a tirar esse parametro pra testar, vou postar o codigo inteiro.